# SQL get rows containing two rows from bridge table

Tags: sql, postgresql

That title is presumably awfully worded. I have some PostgreSQL tables. There is a bridge table, that also holds extra data, so not strictly a bridge, but acts that way also. It goes something like so:

```
player_game
===========
player_game_id PK
player_id FK -> player
game_id FK -> game
other stuff.
```

I want to compile a list of all such game_ids that contain two players of my choice.

So I could find for example, games in which player 1234 played with player 9876.

There can be between 2 and 10 players in a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select pg1.game_id from player_game pg1
inner join player_game pg2 on pg1.game_id = pg2.game_id
where pg1.player_id = 1234
and pg2.player_id = 9876
group by pg1.game_id -- or : AND  pg1.player_game_id < pg2.player_game_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table to itself using an alias. (for both tables) and then specify the two ids as needed

```
 select *
 from player_game as A
 inner join player_game as B on A.game_id = B.game_id
 where A.player_id = '' and B.player_id = ''
```

Comment: It seems `[A]` and `[B]` aliases will not work for PostgreSQL.